# Why doesn't http.ResponseWriter implement a response stream End() call?

Tags: http, go

In Node.js, to finish writing to a stream (and in theory with HTTP, tell the client there is no more data), we use `response.end()`. Using Go, the ResponseWriter interface is like:

```
type ResponseWriter interface {
    Header() Header
    Write([]byte) (int, error)
    WriteHeader(statusCode int)
}
```

so my question is twofold:

1. How can we get the HTTP status code from the ResponseWriter?
2. **more importantly:** How does Go (and routers like Mux) know when the programmer is done writing to the ResponseWriter? Is it when the goroutine ends? What if you wanted to finish the response before the goroutine stack is empty? Seems like an implementation flaw to not have an End() method in the ResponseWriter interface.

Comment: 2) It's done when the handler returns. As to 1, can you clarify what you mean? You write the status code *to* the writer, why are you trying to get the status *from* it in the handler?

Comment: 1) It's not possible to get the status code from the response writer, but the application can record the value set by the application 2) The request is completed when the handler function returns to the net/http server.

Comment: "What if you wanted to finish the response before the goroutine stack is empty?" -- I don't understand what you mean here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Flimzy since I now know the response is considered finished when the handler returns, my elaboration is reworded "what if you want to send the response before the handler returns"? oh wait you can't because there is no End() method :(

Comment: Of course you can. In fact, you must. That's the only option.

Comment: @KCJohnson What problem are you trying to solve by ending the response before the handler returns?  There's probably a simple solution to that problem.

Comment: If you look at the status code retrieval problem, it is an API design problem. I am afraid the behavior of finishing the response when the handler ends will prove to be an API design problem as well. But at the moment, was just curious about how it worked.

Comment: There are estimated to be nearly 2 million Go developers, and they don't seem to have a problem with this API. I would venture a guess this means you're just not accustomed to using it as intended. Is your goal to complain about Go, or to understand how to use it?

Comment: well, let's say you wanted to do more work after the main work of the request was done processed (like a lower priority non-essential write to the database, like notification for a user), I suppose you could just put that on a goroutine, and all would be fine, so I guess there isn't really a problem here, altho the status code retrieval problem is real :)

Comment: Yes, a goroutine is one common way to do work after sending a response. And as explained, the "status code problem" isn't a problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is not possible with the standard `http.ResponseWriter` implementation. But this is an interface, so it's easy to write your own implementation that records the status.  The beginning of a simple implementation might be:

   ```
   type statusRecorder struct {
       http.ResponseWriter
       status int
   }

   func (r *statusRecorder) WriteHeader(status int) {
       r.status = status
       r.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(status)
   }
   ```

   While this may seem like a limitation of the API, it's actually the opposite. By using an interface, it is possible to create an implementation that does anything, or records any information you want, rather than being limited to whatever functionality the standard library authors may have decided to expose.
2. When the handler returns, it is done.  If you wish to do additional work after sending a response, you can spawn a goroutine to continue operating after the main handler returns.

Comment: You also need to implement Write and set status to 200 if status not already set.

Comment: @iLoveReflection: Yes, or infer 200 when it's 0. That's why I said it's only the beginning of an implementation.